# Show that $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}\le \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \le \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic, radicals

I actually would just like a bit of assistance in understanding a step in the solution. I'm just finding it a bit hard to see how the teacher jumped from one step to one step, if someone could spell it out for me that would be great. Thanks so much!

$ \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} }$

I understand this part, as it is just the result of multiplying and dividing by the conjugate. But then the teacher simply has:

Since $ \sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n}$

Then $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}< \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}} $

I probably should know, but could someone just help me out with how he just jumps from the second last step to get the result? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Note $n+1-n = 1$, so $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.$ Make the denominator larger, you make the fraction smaller. And the other way round.

Comment: Note that $$\begin{align} 
\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n}&\implies \sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n> \sqrt{n}+\sqrt n\\
&\implies \dfrac 1{2\sqrt n}>\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} }.\end{align}$$

Comment: I do see that. I'm still struggling. I do see that $ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + {\sqrt{n}}} < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}} $ But then what?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Sorry, I'm obviously a dumbass. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JackReacher It's easy to forget things one previously inferred, don't worry.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be answered [in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736396/show-that-frac12-sqrtn1-le-sqrtn1-sqrtn-le-frac12-sqrt?rq=1#comment1536263_736396), let me summarize (in a CW answer) what is written there:

We have 
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.$$
Thus the original inequality is equivalent to
$$ \frac1{2\sqrt{n+1}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \le \frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$$
which, in turn, is equivalent to
$$2\sqrt{n} \le \sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} \le 2\sqrt{n+1}.$$ 
The validity of these inequalities should be quite easy to see.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you increase the denominator? What can you increase to reach required inequality on left? What would happen if you would have decreased it?

Answer (score 0):

*Another approach to the proof, since Martin Sleziak already answered on the step that puzzles you.*

This one is a classic application of [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

For a differentiable function $f$ on $[a,b]$, you have that

$$\inf_{[a,b]} f'\leq\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leq \sup_{[a,b]} f'$$

Here, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on interval $[n,n+1]$, and $f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$, which is decreasing, thus

$$\frac1{2\sqrt{n+1}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n+1-n}\leq\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}$$